# how can sort chart all columns which they are in the different series

Tags: c#, sorting, charts

I have some data about personnel worked time . for show this data , i used visual studio chart(c# language) . this data is divide between chart series . when i want  sort all columns ,they had been sorting between their series member, but i want sort all columns with each other to find  top 10 member . what can  do?

```
private void TakeSeries()
    {
        var q1 = (from n1 in db.tblSelectedOperation
                  join n2 in db.Operations
                  on n1.OpCode equals n2.OperationCode
                  select new { n2.OperationName }).ToList();
        foreach (var item in q1)
        {
            if (chart1.Series.FindByName(item.OperationName) == null)
            {
                Series ser = new Series(item.OperationName);
                chart1.Series.Add(ser);
                chart1.Series[item.OperationName].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                chart1.Series[item.OperationName].LabelBackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
```

//---------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------

```
#region showValueInChart
        //var q1 = db.usp_ForGroupsOfProductionWithScore(Setting.Setting.Date()).ToList();
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        foreach (var item in chart1.Series)
        {
            chart1.Series[item.Name.ToString()].Points.Clear();
            var q0 = q1.Where(n => n.OperationName == item.Name.ToString()).ToList();
            if (q0 != null)
            {
                foreach (var item1 in q0)
                {
                    chart1.Series[item1.OperationName].Points.AddXY(item1.personName.ToString(), (int)(item1.Score));
                }
            }
            chart1.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();
        }
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;

        #endregion
```

Comment: Which UI framework Winforms? WPF, Asp.Net? and also which chart library you use? Very important: post your code.. Please refer to [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : i think it's WPF.. 
library :DataVisualization

Comment: C'mon, you should __know__ this! Which is it: System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting or System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting ?? - You don't sort Columns, you need to sort the data !

Comment: this is my chart : [link](http://share.pho.to/8fhoc/gn/original)   and this is sample what i want sorted like that: [link](http://share.pho.to/8g23U/j2/original)

Comment: @TaW : "using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;" - I used all sort function and method what i found when i'm searching. but none of them sort the chart columns . i sorted "q1 var" before i use it , or sorted "q0" but after all of that still sorted the column in series group . . for example i used : - q1.orderby(n=>n.score) //\\ q0.orderby(n=>n.score)) -chart1.DataManipulator.Sort(PointSortOrder.Descending,item.Name.ToString()); - chart1.Series[0].Sort(PointSortOrder.Descending); but they don't sorted like what i want..

Answer (score 0):

I've found it.. i couldn't sort chart column as i wanted because i had added data with series order .. 
after i deleted that rows from code , chart sorted correctly.

```
#region showValueInChart
        q1 = q1.OrderByDescending(n => n.Score).ToList();
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        foreach (var item in chart1.Series)
        {
            chart1.Series[item.Name.ToString()].Points.Clear();
        }
        //var q0 = q1.Where(n => n.OperationName == item.Name.ToString()).OrderByDescending(n => n.Score).ToList();
        //if (q0 != null)
        //{
            //q0 = q0.OrderByDescending(n => n.Score).ToList();
            foreach (var item1 in q1)
            {
                chart1.Series[item1.OperationName].Points.AddXY(item1.personName.ToString(), (int)(item1.Score));
                chart1.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();
            }
        //}
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;
        #endregion
```